# Compare Two Lists and Remove the Same Item

Tags: c#, list

Using `foreach`, I want to loop through two different lists and find the same ID, then remove that item.

For example:

```
IList<Student> studentList1 = new List<Student> 
{ 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John" },
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve" },
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill" } 
};

IList<Student> studentList2 = new List<Student> 
{                    
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill" },
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" },
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" } 
};
```

How can I loop through both `studentList1` and `studentList2`, and then remove the object in studentList2 where `StudentID = 3`?

Comment: You can use LINQ method `Where`, or method `Remove` of `List`

Comment: Please be specific `then remove that item` remove it from both lists, or one list, or pick our favourite

Comment: Sorry, remove the item from studentList2

Comment: Is there a way to use foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Student` class declared something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int? StudentID { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"StudentID={StudentID} StudentName={StudentName}";
    }
}
```

You can use [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Linq`:

```
var removedList2 = studentList2
    .Where(s2 => !studentList1
    .Any(s1 => s1.StudentID == s2.StudentID));

foreach (var student in removedList2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
// StudentID=4 StudentName=Ram
// StudentID=5 StudentName=Ron
```

However, the above is pretty inefficient since you need to scan the whole first list for lookups, which is O(N). An improvement would be to store the ids from the first list into a `HashSet<int?>`, then lookups are O(1) instead using [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var ids = new HashSet<int?>(studentList1.Select(s1 => s1.StudentID));

var removedList2 = studentList2.Where(s2 => !ids.Contains(s2.StudentID));

foreach (var student in removedList2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
// StudentID=4 StudentName=Ram
// StudentID=5 StudentName=Ron
```

With just foreach loops you can use [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var ids = new HashSet<int?>();
foreach (var s1 in studentList1)
{
    ids.Add(s1.StudentID);
}

for (var i = studentList2.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (ids.Contains(studentList2[i].StudentID))
    {
        studentList2.Remove(studentList2[i]);
    }
}

foreach (var student in studentList2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
// StudentID=4 StudentName=Ram
// StudentID=5 StudentName=Ron
```

Comment: Thank you. However I just realized I cannot use the linq because the two lists are not using the same object schema. Is there a way to use foreach loop?

Comment: Thank you again for the modif.. however this time with the HashSet I got error: "Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.iEnumerable<int?> to System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>". The Id actually was set to int? because of nullable. This is how I declare it: 
public int? StudentID { get; set; }

Comment: @ichachan No worries, I modified the code to use nullable `int?` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure but this code seems to fail if two items needs to be removed because you're using an index to access the list members and remove them from the same list. Iterating from last to first will fix that issue. **EDIT** [Validated](https://ideone.com/b7dD1C)

Comment: @SebastianSchumann I appreciate your edit, missed that one :P